# Computer Generated If-Statements to create A.I

Tags: randomness

Just a thought-experiment, could a program be written so that the computer generates it's own if-statements (semi/randomly) and runs them, gathers the results, then tests them in new scenarios, and iterates from there?

This idea came to me because it's kind of how we humans operate.  When we're born, we have a genetic foundation (programming language), and through experience, trial-and-error, cause and effect, etc. we learn about our world and create new "truths" about our world and ourselves (if-statements that are found to be 'true' are ones that were tested and had some kind of result).

How a program would deem an if-statement has worth is what I'm unsure of, at this point.  It would generate so many non-sensical if-statements, but eventually one would be written that could pass.  Most likely, it would have to tie in to some other network, like with humans it's our sensory organs, so whatever analog for a computer we could make that would tie-in to its if-statement library.

What do you think?

Comment: I'm not an expert hence I am here to read some good answers. Btw, your idea about building new truths through experience made me think about "Conflict-driven clause learning", which is a technique used by SAT-Solvers to build new true statements from a starting knowledge.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning ?